# Converting a JSON dir tree into indented plain text in GoLang

Tags: json, go, plaintext

I have a dir tree in a JSON struct that I'm trying to format in plain text. Formatting it in XML or YAML is pretty easy. Formatting it in plain text is much harder than I thought.

The JSON struct is formatted like this :

```
type File struct {
   Name     string  `json:"Name"`
   Children []*File `json:"Children"`
}
```

Since the JSON structure allows for 'children', the JSON is nested, and since it's a dir tree, I don't know how deep the nesting will get (within reason).

I need the converted JSON to look like this :

```
base_dir
  sub_dir_1
  sub_dir_2
    file_in_sub_dir_2
  sub_dir_3
  ...
```

Can anyone tell me how this could be done in a reasonably simple way? Right now I'm having to brute force with lots of looping and indenting with tabs, and I'm just sure there's a more elegant way in Go.

Comment: Thanks for the edit voutasaurus.

Answer (score 3):

Write a function to recurse down the directory tree printing a file and its children. Increase the indent level when recursing down the tree.

```
func printFile(f *File, indent string) {
   fmt.Printf("%s%s\n", indent, f.Name)
   for _, f := range f.Children {
     printFile(f, indent+"  ")
   }
}
```

Call the function with the root of the tree:

```
printFile(root, "")
```

<kbd>[run the code on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ssLo3YpFIY)</kbd>

Comment: This works perfectly - many thanks. I didn't consider a recursive call into the printing function itself, which of course now is an obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [MarshalIndent](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent). Here is a <kbd>[go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/R-k6WnPnQ_)</kbd> example.

```
instance := MyStruct{12344, "ohoasdoh", []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
res, _ := json.MarshalIndent(instance, "", "  ")
fmt.Println(string(res))
```

Which will give you something like:

```
{
  "Num": 12344,
  "Str": "ohoasdoh",
  "Arr": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but json.MarshalIndent outputs JSON (as it should). I was looking for a plain text output that's more human readable.

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the question, I upvoted it because it was the first result on Google where I was looking for exactly this.